# NoReverseMatch at /Gyobera/

Tags: python, django

I am new to django; though same bugs have been tackled here, I honestly can't locate where my code has gone wrong.

This is the error I get:

```
NoReverseMatch at /Gyobera/
Reverse for 'classification' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['classification/(?P<classification_name_url>\\w+)/$']
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/Gyobera/
Django Version: 1.8.2
Exception Type: NoReverseMatch
Exception Value:    
Reverse for 'classification' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['classification/(?P<classification_name_url>\\w+)/$']
Exception Location: C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\core\urlresolvers.py in _reverse_with_prefix, line 496
Python Executable:  C:\Python34\python.exe
Python Version: 3.4.2
Python Path:    
['C:\\Users\\Scott Businge\\Ewange',
 'C:\\Python34\\lib\\site-packages\\pip-7.1.0-py3.4.egg',
 'C:\\Users\\Scott Businge\\Ewange',
 'C:\\WINDOWS\\SYSTEM32\\python34.zip',
 'C:\\Python34\\DLLs',
 'C:\\Python34\\lib',
 'C:\\Python34',
 'C:\\Users\\Scott Businge\\AppData\\Roaming\\Python\\Python34\\site-packages',
 'C:\\Python34\\lib\\site-packages']
Server time:    Mon, 15 Feb 2016 08:48:43 +0300
```

Links can't be clicked to show detailed pages, everytime I click it shows the error from the index page which I will post here down. I am only using the project urls(Ewange)

index.html

```
        <h2><strong>Main Classifications</strong></h2>
          {% if classifications %}
            <ul>
                {% for classification in classifications %}
                 <!-- Following line changed to add an HTML hyperlink -->
                <li><a href="{% url 'classification' classification.url %}">{{ classification.name }}</a></li>
                {% endfor %}
            </ul>
        {% else %}
            <strong>There are no classifications present.</strong>
        {% endif %}
{% endblock %}
```

urls.py

```
url(r'^classification/(?P<classification_name_url>\w+)/$', views.classification,
                           name='classification'),
```

views.py

```
def index(request):
    context = RequestContext(request)
    classification_list = Classification.objects.order_by('-likes')[:6]
    context_dict = {'classifications': classification_list}
    for classification in classification_list:
        classification.url = classification.name.replace(' ', '_')
    return render_to_response('index.html', context_dict, context)

def classification(request, classification_name_url):
    context = RequestContext(request)
    classification_name = classification_name_url.replace('_', ' ')
    context_dict = {'classification_name': classification_name, 'classification_name_url': classification_name_url}
    try:
        classification = Classification.objects.get(name=classification_name)
        context_dict['classification'] = classification
        lists = List.objects.filter(classification=classification)
        context_dict['lists'] = lists
    except Classification.DoesNotExist:
        return render_to_response('gyobera/classification.html', context_dict, context)
```

classification.html

```
<h1>{{ classification_name }}</h1>
{% if classification %}
    {% if lists %}
    <ul>
        {% for list in lists %}
        <li><a href="{{ list.title }}">{{ list.title }}</a></li>
        {% endfor %}
    </ul>
    {% else %}
        <strong>No lists currently in classification.</strong>
    {% endif %}
{% else %}
    The specified classification {{ classification_name }} does not exist!
{% endif %}
```

setings.py

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'Gyobera',
)

MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
)

ROOT_URLCONF = 'Ewange.urls'
```

when i run the server, i still get the "NoReverseMatchError"
here is the current state of the urls.py, views.py and link in the index.html.
what i was asking is, after correcting the classification.list_set, do u have to change the context_dict and url matching in views and urls.py respectively..

```
NoReverseMatch at /Gyobera/
Reverse for 'classification' with arguments '('',)' and keyword arguments '{}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['classification/(?P<classification_name_url>\\w+)/$']
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/Gyobera/
Django Version: 1.8.2
Exception Type: NoReverseMatch
Exception Value:    
Reverse for 'classification' with arguments '('',)' and keyword arguments '{}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['classification/(?P<classification_name_url>\\w+)/$']
Exception Location: C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\core\urlresolvers.py in _reverse_with_prefix, line 496
```

urls.py

```
url(r'^classification/(?P<classification_name_url>\w+)/$', views.classification,
                           name='classification'),
```

views.py

```
def classification(request, classification_name_url):
    context = RequestContext(request)
    classification_name = classification_name_url.replace('_', ' ')
    context_dict = {'classification_name': classification_name, 'classification_name_url': classification_name_url}
    try:
        classification = Classification.objects.get(name=classification_name)
        context_dict['classification'] = classification
        lists = List.objects.filter(classification=classification)
        context_dict['lists'] = lists
    except Classification.DoesNotExist:
        return render_to_response('gyobera/classification.html', context_dict, context)
```

index.html

```
  {% if classifications %}
    <ul>
        {% for classification in classifications %}
         <!-- Following line changed to add an HTML hyperlink -->
        <li><a href="{% url 'classification' classification.list_set.url %}"></a></li>
        {% endfor %}
    </ul>
{% else %}
```

Comment: Please post the stack trace.

Comment: let me post it down @Sayse

Answer (score 0):

You're getting the error because the classification you're looking at doesn't have a url, and it doesn't have a url because you never save the changes to the model in your view. I'm not convinced its a good idea to save changes to the model every time someone loads the index page however.

```
def index(request):
    context = RequestContext(request)
    classification_list = Classification.objects.order_by('-likes')[:6]
    for classification in classification_list:
        classification.url = classification.name.replace(' ', '_')
        classification.save()

    context_dict = {'classifications': classification_list}
    return render_to_response('index.html', context_dict, context)
```

Answer (score -2):

```
<li><a href="{% url 'classification' classification.url %}">
...
```

Classification does not have a url field, so there is no argument for the "classification" url. This is why the error says `with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{}`, that is: no arguments.

The actual relation: one classification has many lists, and each list has a url field. So a single classification has more than one url, via the List model.

To access the all the lists of a single classification, you use:

```
classification.list_set #list_set is the default, when you don't use related_name
```

This can give more than one list, so either loop through the lists of this classification, or select one, something like:

```
<li><a href="{% url 'classification' classification.list_set.first().url %}">
```

Comment: it's showing the same @Aviah. let me post the stack trace

Comment: Let's try to debug it, I suspect it's something with the name/url. Instead of `{% url 'classification' classification.url %}` try a value from the table, like `{% url 'classification' foobaz %}`. Also, can you post the model?

Comment: yeah, the model is here down.

Comment: Even when i put a value from the table, it shows "NoRreverseMatchError" @Aviah

Comment: thanks Aviah, but do i have to reflect the changes in the urls.py and views.py i.e to put "classification.list_set" where i had "classification_name_url" because when i put that, it shows no arguments in the first list.. in the IDE, it shows an error = expected % at first()

Comment: What do you want to do? When you have a classification you need all it lists url? what is a list url?